# Protractor with Typescript 2.0.0 duplicate identifier issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, typescript, npm, protractor, typescript2.0

I am upgrading to use Typescript 2.0 with Protractor 4.0.5. I am upgrading a project from typescript 1.8 and protractor 3.8. I have come accross a bunch of problems, which I share here:

My package.json is:

```
{
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "2.2.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"web-request": "^1.0.3",
"zone.js": "0.6.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
"@types/node": "^6.0.45",
"@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.33",
"es6-promise": "3.1.2",
"es6-promise-loader": "1.0.1",
"es6-shim": "0.35.0",
"es7-reflect-metadata": "1.6.0",
"exports-loader": "0.6.3",
"imports-loader": "0.6.5",
"jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.0",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
"phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7",
"pix-diff": "^1.0.14",
"protractor": "4.0.5",
"protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.6",
"protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.3.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"rimraf": "2.5.2",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
"ts-node": "0.7.1",
"tslint": "3.7.4",
"tslint-loader": "2.1.3",
"typedoc": "0.4.3",
"typescript": "^2.0.0-beta",
"underscore": "^1.8.3"
 }
```

Then my package json is:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types":[
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "compiler": "node_modules/typescript"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

When I try to run protractor tests with that setup, I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
node_modules\@types\selenium-webdriver\index.d.ts (12,11): Duplicate identifier 'Driver'. (2300)
node_modules\@types\selenium-webdriver\index.d.ts (46,11): Duplicate identifier 'Options'. (2300)
node_modules\@types\selenium-webdriver\index.d.ts (310,11): Duplicate identifier 'ServiceBuilder'. (2300)
node_modules\protractor\typings\globals\selenium-webdriver\index.d.ts (12,11): Duplicate identifier 'Driver'. (2300)
node_modules\protractor\typings\globals\selenium-webdriver\index.d.ts (46,11): Duplicate identifier 'Options'. (2300)
node_modules\protractor\typings\globals\selenium-webdriver\index.d.ts (310,11): Duplicate identifier 'ServiceBuilder'. (2300)
```

How to resolve that issue, since I belive everything is setup properly. I am using Protractor 4.0.5 which should be working with typescript 2.0.

Comment: Can you add a minimal `*.ts` file that causes the problem? I don't know anything about Protractor but this seems like a problem with the type definition so I can try to help.

Comment: @HuyNguyen Ok. I will add example repository later on today.

Answer (score 2):

Protractor removed the type declarations in the version 5.x versions, so you can simply upgrade the version of Protractor you're using and the problem should go away.

If you have/want to stay on version 4.0.5, you can always uninstall the webdriver types, by running:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/selenium-webdriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open an issue at `protractor`. It should not deploy the typings of `selenium-webdriver` in its package.

For now, try this ugly hack to see if it remedy the problem:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/protractor/typings/global/selenium-webdriver"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this. I modified `typeRoots` and `exclude`

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types":[
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules/protractor/node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "compiler": "node_modules/typescript"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

I created a template for configuring Protractor with TypeScript 2:  https://github.com/suvroc/protractor-typescript-template

It may be useful for you